# Is 그래 a contracted form of 그렇다?

Tags: verb-endings, suffix, contraction

I came across occurrences of 그래 and 그렇 while reading a French Assimil-collection textbook (whose approach is progressive assimilation, rather than thorough grammatical explanations from the very beginning) and I wonder if both roots are related, since one can find "modified radicals" quite often in Korean (for example, the 모르다 -> 몰라요 type, or 하다 -> 해요). Perhaps 그래 is a modified form of 그렇다 to be used with a specific set of suffixes, while other suffixes require 그렇?

So far, I found the following examples:

그래 - Yes.

그래도 - Yes, but...

그렇지만 - Yes, but...

그렇다 - (infinitive)

그렇게 - so (much) / to such an extent

그러면 - If it's so...

I just can't understand the absence of ㅎ in 그러면.

To sum up, two questions:

1. Is 그래 a 'mutated' variant of 그렇, or an independent verbal root?
2. Does the last ㅎ of verbal roots disappear before some suffixes?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is 그래 a 'mutated' variant of 그렇, or an independent verbal root?
>    **It is a variant, but I would say a logically expected one rather than mutated.**
> 2. Does the last ㅎ of verbal roots disappear before some suffixes?
>    **Yes, the last ㅎ is dropped before a vowel.  e.g. 하얘 (하얗(다) -> 하얗 + -아/어/여/얘 -> 하얗애 -> 하얘).**

The key to understanding 그래, 그렇다 and all the related forms is knowing the original form that evolved to them, which is 그러하다.

> - **그러하다 = (it) is so.**     Before a consonant, ㅓ하 contracts to ㅎ or just disappears.
>
>   1. 그러하게 -> 그렇게, 그러하다 -> 그렇다, 그러하지만 -> 그렇지만 (ㅎ before ㄱ, ㄷ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅈ).
>   2. 그러한 -> 그런, 그러하면 -> 그러면, 그러해 -> 그래 (drops before ㄴ, ㅁ, or a vowel)
> - **그래 = 그러하다 + -여 -> 그러하여 -> 그러해 -> 그래** (하여 always contracts to 해).

That's how 그래 came about, but there's more to it.  그래 isn't always just 그러하다/그렇다 in -아/어/여 ending.  Another big chunk of its usage is as 그**리**하다/그러다 + -여, where 그러다 is different from 그렇다.

Comparison of 그렇다 and 그러다.

> - **그러하다 / 그렇다 (adj) = is so.**     (e.g. 그렇지 않아 = It *is* not so)
> - **그리하다 / 그러다 (= 그렇게 하다) (verb) = do so.**     (e.g. 그러지 마 = Don't *do* that)

그리 is basically a short form of 그러하게/그렇게 (in that way), so 그리하다 is a verb phrase with 그러하게/그렇게 embedded in it.

그리하다/그러다 conjugates to 그런다 in present tense -다 ending form.  The sentence ending -다 is the only case where verb and adjective have different forms. Verbs have the -ㄴ/는 to their stem, as in 한다 (하다), 간다 (가다), 먹는다 (먹다), 갖는다 (갖다), whereas adjectives have the same form as the base form, as in 크다 (크다), 길다  (길다), 행복하다 (행복하다). So a word that is both a verb and adjective (e.g. 크다 = 1, big (adj), 2. grow (v)) has two conjugated forms, like 크다 (adj) and 큰다 (verb), in the present tense -다 ending.

In the case of -아/어/여, which is a sentence ending most commonly used in ordinary speech, verbs and adjectives are not differentiated in the suffix.  This leads to both 그렇다 and 그러다 becoming 그래 in the present tense (before contraction they are different as 그**러**해 and 그**리**해), and 그랬어 for past (그러했어, 그리했어), and 그럴 거야 for future (그러할 거야, 그리할 거야).  Of these, the shortest forms 그래, 그랬어, and 그럴 are used in most cases (the others are only occasionally seen in formal writings).

In addition to the dual role of verb and adjective, the same -아/어/여 ending of 그래 is used for declarative and imperative and interrogative endings (그건 그래 = that is right, 그러지 마 = Don't do that, 그래? = Is that so?).  So 그래 is one phrase that has half a dozen different uses.